# Why does the pythagorean theorem contradict the geometrical interpretation of length contraction?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

While I was taking a course in SR, we derived the length contraction formula using Lorentz transformations, however, when I tried to graph the space-time diagram of a ruler at rest being observed by a moving reference frame with a velocity v:
[image: Space-time diagram, with a beam of light going in the middle.]

I saw that the x' in the moving reference "could" be calculated using the Pythagorean theorem, however, there has been a slight offset:
Using the theorem and using the fact that $t=vx$ (since at the start $t=t'=0$, and replacing it in the time Lorentz transformation we get that result):
$\sqrt(x^2+x^2v^2)=x'$ or simply $x\sqrt(1+v^2)=x'$.
However the actual formula we know is:
$x'=x\sqrt(1-v^2)$. If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it!

And also, if something is unclear please do tell me!

Comment: special relativity obeys hyperbolic geometry, whereas you are thinking in Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Oh, right, I remember using cosh's and sinh's a lot throughout the lecture. So wait, is there some equivalent for it in hyperbolic geometry? Because, now i can see, kind of, "why" the "t" component must be inverted, is it something to do with the relation that $cosh(x)^2-sinh(x)^2=1$? I'm sorry if this sounds a bit too hand-wavy. And thanks for replying!

Comment: You should review the notion of Minkowski space (or Minkowski metric): https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Minkowski_space. For 4D Euclidean space, the metric is (+1,+1,+1,+1), while for Minkowski space, the metric is (-1,+1,+1,+1).

Comment: Oh wow, that really cleared up some questions I had in mind! Does this also relate to how proper time looks a bit like vector magnitude but with inverted time component ($\tau^2=-t^2+x^2+y^2+z^2$)? Thanks again!

Comment: for a short segment, yes, $d\tau^2 = -dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$. For a general curve on the spacetime, you'd have to a take a line integral of those segments.

Comment: Yeh! Thanks a lot!